# Linux Bash scripting how to use a range of parameters

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, scripting

how can i use a range of parameters in linux bash like  60-70 -->  ($1 - $2)

```
case $1 in
           $1-$2 )
                echo "test"
                shift;;

         ....) ....
```

Comment: you can't. the clauses in case statements must be single values. you're basically doing a literal comparison of `$1` to whatever `$1-$2` produces as a string, e.g. `case 'foo' IN   'foo-bar')`

Comment: They don't have to be single values; they can be patterns. Patterns, however, don't handle numeric ranges well.

Comment: okay thanks , but i need a solution can you help me? @chepner

Comment: @MarcB can you give me a solution?

Comment: Even if we had numeric-range pattern-matching syntax, `$1` is *always* going to be in the (inclusive) range `$1-$2`. That makes it a little hard for someone to show a working example derived from your code. Maybe you meant to check whether `$1` is in the range between `$2` and `$3`? (If so, do you have any guarantees as to which if these is greater or less than the other?)

Answer (score 2):

Each case of a `case` statement is a pattern, but depending on the range, it can be tricky to specify a good pattern. `60-70`, for instance, could be matched with

```
case $1 in
    6[0-9] | 70) echo "test"
                 shift ;;
```

Essentially, you have to treat the numbers as digit strings, and match them as text. A range like 67-93, for instance, breaks down into the fairly unwieldy

```
6[7-9] | [78][0-9] | 9[0-3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function for it.
When you have different ranges, make parameters like range(check, minimum, maximum).
Return 1 when check < minimimum, 0 when check inside boundaries 
(or equal boundary) and 2 above:

```
range() {
   if [ "$1" -lt "$2" ]; then
      return 1
   fi
   if [ "$1" -gt "$3" ]; then
      return 2
   fi
   return 0
}
```

When you want different returns for different ranges, change this function.
EDIT: Added quotes and made positive return values.
EDIT 2: changed `function x` into `x()`

Comment: Needs more quotes to avoid some bad values (empty values, multi-word values, glob characters, etc) causing test-command syntax errors rather than (more conventional) invalid-comparison data errors. And if you're going to use the POSIX-incompatible `function` keyword, why not go whole hog and use non-POSIX math syntax too? `if (( $1 < $3 ))`, etc. Also, `-1` isn't a valid return value; only single-byte integers are allowed, so this currently exits with an error in the first case handled.